# Naming complementary angle

Tags: geometry, notation, angle, convention

Is there a simple, standard way of writing the complementary angle of $\alpha$, namely $90^\circ - \alpha$? And what about the supplementary angle?

Comment: I haven't seen special notation for neither the complimentary nor supplementary angle to $\angle A$.

Comment: I've used the notation "co$\alpha$" informally. (It's easier to see with taller angle names; eg, "co$\theta$" or "co$A$".) This fits with the whole "co-" prefix convention for complementary functions in trig, so that I can write stuff like $$\cos\theta = \sin(\text{co}\theta)$$ I've not had use for supplementary angle notation, but I'd probably use "su$\theta$" for consistency.

Comment: @Blue for your example, $\cos t = \sin (90 - t)$ does not look any worse...

Comment: @gt6989b: The context for stuff like that is specifically to highlight the connection of complementary angles and complementary functions. Consider, for instance, how the relation *reads*: "the co-sine of theta is the sine of co-theta". Anyway, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Various authors on the history of trigonometry use a vinculum over the arc/angle to denote the complement. See:

- Jenson: Abū Nasr Mansūr's Approach to Spherical Astronomy as Developed in His Treatise “The Table of Minutes”, p4.
- Berggren: Spherical Trigonometry in Kūshyār ibn Labbān's Jāmi Zij, p17.
- King: Ibn Yūnus' Very Useful Tables for Reckoning Time by the Sun, p351.
- Debarnot: in the Encyclopedia of the History of Arabic Science, Vol 2, p177.